# Ansible - prevent gathering facts for hosts that are not used

Tags: ansible

I have a `playbook.yml` along the lines:

```
- name: Play1
  hosts: vm1
  ...
  tags: pl1

- name: Play2
  hosts: vm2
  ...
  tags: pl2
```

Now imagine scenario, that `vm1` is dead and I don't care about it for the time being and I want to run only the 2nd play like this:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --tags=pl2
```

But now, Ansible fails with the error when gathering facts for `vm1`. Is there a way to instruct Ansible to be smarter and ignore other plays completely? And why does it even do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>If you really think that's the best way to manage your servers...</sup>

Use `gather_facts: false` and add explicitly a `setup` task:

```
- name: Play1
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: vm1
  pre_tasks:
    - setup:
  ...
  tags: pl1
```

Comment: More details would be helpful.  So admin would edit file setting gather_facts yes/no as needed?  Why is a setup pre-task required?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `--limit` option, which only runs tasks on the specified host(s) and/or group(s).

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --limit=vm2
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/intro_patterns.html